# Comparing rows values using shift function

Tags: python, pandas

I'm learning pandas and I came across the following method to compare rows in a dataframe.

Here I'm using `np.were` and `shift()` functions to compare values within a column.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

# Initialise data to Dicts of series. 
d = {'col' : pd.Series([10, 30, 20, 40, 70, 60])} 

# creates Dataframe. 
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df['Relation'] = np.where(df['col'] > df['col'].shift(), "Grater", "Less")
df
```

Here the output appearing as the following:

```
    col Relation
0   10  Less
1   30  Grater
2   20  Less
3   40  Grater
4   70  Grater
5   60  Less
```

I have confusion in row 3 why it is appearing as `Grater`?, 40 is less than 70 so it should appear as `Less`. What I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because compare `40` with `20`, because shift index by `1`:

```
df['Relation'] = np.where(df['col'] > df['col'].shift(), "Grater", "Less")

df['shifted'] = df['col'].shift()
df['m'] = df['col'] > df['col'].shift()
print (df)

   col Relation  shifted      m
0   10     Less      NaN  False
1   30   Grater     10.0   True
2   20     Less     30.0  False
3   40   Grater     20.0   True <- here
4   70   Grater     40.0   True
5   60     Less     70.0  False
```

Maybe you want shift by `-1`:

```
df['Relation'] = np.where(df['col'] > df['col'].shift(-1), "Grater", "Less")

df['shifted'] = df['col'].shift(-1)
df['m'] = df['col'] > df['col'].shift(-1)
print (df)

   col Relation  shifted      m
0   10     Less     30.0  False
1   30   Grater     20.0   True
2   20     Less     40.0  False
3   40     Less     70.0  False
4   70   Grater     60.0   True
5   60     Less      NaN  False
```